# Google Sheets Apps Script updating values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code which updates Sheet1 from a HTML table
At midnight the website clears the entries and starts with a new list
I want to keep a list of the data, and I want it to stay even after the page resets at midnight.

This is what I have:

```
  function Import() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Updating")
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("=IMPORTHTML(\"https://www.scottcountyiowa.us/sheriff/temp-inmates.php?comdate=today\",\"table\", 1 )")
}
//THE ABOVE WORKS GREAT OPERATES LIKE IT SHOULD


//THIS IS A START BUT IT ISN'T FUNCTIONING
function onChange(e) 
{
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart>1 && e.range.getSheet().getName()=="Updating") 
  {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).setValue(e.value);
    var sh=source.getSheetByName('Static');
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).setValue(e.value);
  }
}
```

When I set the project trigger to run on edit, it displays the error percentage, it always fails, I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'columnStart' of undefined at onChange(Code:3:14)

Comment: Welcome. May I clarify something; please correct me if I am wrong. You have a function `onChange(e)`. This is an installable trigger. However your question refers to "a trigger to run on edit", and the event attributes are those of onEdit. Would you clarify whether you installed onChange() as an installable trigger and the Event Type is "On edit". On a tangent, it would be advisable, even for the sake of clarity, to give the function a different name.

Comment: I wrote atleast some of the bottom one but I was under the impression that you wanted to use an onEdit trigger and the event blocks are completely different. [See Event Blocks](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).  So you should delete that and rewrite.

Comment: You must use an onEdit trigger as an onChange will only trigger if a structural change on the spreadsheet is done (such as renaming a sheet or deleting a column). [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers). Also, remember to actually install the trigger and delete it every time you make changes on the code. **Also, could you please share a sample of your sheet so that it is easier to see if everything is right and to clarify what you are aiming for here?**